# How to iterate over a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset of users, books and ratings and I want to find users who rated high particular book and to those users I want to find what other books they liked too.

My data looks like:

```
df.sample(5)

    User-ID     ISBN    Book-Rating
49064   102967  0449244741  8
60600   251150  0452264464  9
376698  52853   0373710720  7
454056  224764  0590416413  7
54148   25409   0312421273  9
```

I did so far:

```
df_p = df.pivot_table(index='ISBN', columns='User-ID', values='Book-Rating').fillna(0)
lotr = df_p.ix['0345339703'] # Lord of the Rings Part 1
like_lotr = lotr[lotr > 7].to_frame()
users = like_lotr['User-ID']
```

last line failed for

> KeyError: 'User-ID'

I want to obtain users who rated LOTR > 7 to those users further find movies they liked too from the matrix.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: check your `df.columns`. Likely that you have some extra space either before or after the `User-ID` part. The name of the column should be exactly right otherwise a `KeyError` will be raised

Comment: @rafaelc It says only Index(['0345339703'], dtype='object') which is weird since I cast it into a frame.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: what is the exact output of `df.columns` ? paste it here

Comment: @serafeim Output: Index(['0345339703'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `like_lotr` dataframe `'User-ID'` is the name of the index, you cannot select it like a normal column. That is why the line `users = like_lotr['User-ID']` raises a `KeyError`. It is not a column.

Moreover `ix` is deprecated, better to use `loc` in your case. And don't put quotes: it need to be an integer, since `'User-ID'` was originally a column of integers (at least from your sample).

Try like this:

```
df_p = df.pivot_table(index='ISBN', columns='User-ID', values='Book-Rating').fillna(0)
lotr = df_p.loc[452264464] # used another number from your sample dataframe to test this code.
like_lotr = lotr[lotr > 7].to_frame()
users = like_lotr.index.tolist()
```

`user` is now a list with the ids you want.

Using your small sample above and the number I used to test, `user` is `[251150]`.

---

An alternative solution is to use `reset_index`. The two last lins should look like this:

```
like_lotr = lotr[lotr > 7].to_frame().reset_index()
users = like_lotr['User-ID']
```

`reset_index` put the index back in the columns.

Comment: Yes, that's it! But how do I now filter the dataset/matrix to keep only those users and find what books they rated high?

Comment: That would be another question. However, once you have the ids in the `users` you can go back to your original dataframe and do: `df.loc[df['User-ID'].isin(users)]`. This will select all the users and from here you can get the other data you want.